# What failure modes should I expect when using relocatable virtualenvs?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm using python with virtualenvs, and I keep assuming that they're relocatable by default and they aren't. I know HOW to make them relocatable, but I'm not sure why this is necessary.

So, the question is: given that I've made my virtualenvs relocatable, what failure modes should I be on the lookout for?

Virtualenvs are by default, made not-relocatable, and it's difficult to make them truly relocatable. What problems does this prevent, and what am I inviting by using the feature?

Comment: Shouldn't you ask the authors of `virtualenv` abot that?

Comment: @phd I've got a question on the python forums as well...

Comment: *I'm not sure why this is necessary* is a complete offtopic at SO.